# Why is it bad practice to use dot notation for "side effects."

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm in chapter 13 of iOS Programming from Big Nerd Ranch and for the life of me I don't see why I would want to use `[self becomeFirstResponder];` rather than `self.becomeFirstResponder;`

When I type it the latter way, `self.becomeFirstResponder;`, I get a warning "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects" It still works as intended but why on earth would I use brackets when I find dot notation easier.

My question: What are these side-effects that could happen by using dot notation in this manner?

Comment: You're probably not going to find an answer that satisfies you. It's just Objective-C convention, plain and simple. You can do what you're doing; it works. It will just "look" wrong to other Objective-C devs. It's the same way you can make a function called `getFoo` instead of `foo` -- it's not *technically wrong*, it just goes against convention. "Why on earth would I use brackets when I find dot notation easier"? Because it's idiomatic; that's all. It's the same reason you should use camelCase instead of underscores in your method names.

Comment: If InsertWittyName's answer is all correct then I like that answer, and it makes total sense to me now. Many of the functions I use are used as setters and I don't care about the return value--hence why I was confused for the warnings--haven't had to worry about a return value on simple things like this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`becomeFirstResponder` is not a property, it's a method on `UIResponser`.

However, you're treating it as a property by using the dot notation, and ignoring the return value, which is why you get the warning.

Comment: Aha! This is simple yet a perfect explaination. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking the wrong question: the side effect is what you want — it's that `self` becomes first responder. That's the side effect that **definitely will** occur.

The point the compiler is making is that dot notation shouldn't be used deliberately to trigger those side effects; it's probably partly that whether the compiler will substitute a call to the getter or the setter (or both) will depend on the context of your use of the dot notation, partly that the compiler may want to make assumptions about getting a return result if it is told to call a getter and partly that your code will just look wrong and therefore read incorrectly to a human.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. May be compiler can omit your's `self.becomeFirstResponder;` with high optimization level, because you doesn't use property result.